# Total Sum by user id and action taken by user php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
id  post_id     meta_key     meta_value
1   101         tweet_point        5
2   101         tweet_user_id      1
3   101         email_point        10
4   102         fb_point           10
5   102         fb_user_id         1
6   101         email_user_id      2
7   101         chat_point         5
8   102         tweet_point        2 
9   102         tweet_user_id      2
10  101         chat_user_id       2
```

From above table if user id  does a tweet on one post, and a fb post on another post I want  to  sum those point together.

The user id is in column meta_value corresponding to meta_key column for example tweet_user_id, email_user_id, chat_user_id, fb_user_id.
Same way points for each action eg fb_point, tweet_point are also stored in meta_value column corresponding to meta_key value for eg tweet_point, fb_point.

How I can do this in php mysql. I am using wordpress.
The result I am seeing is as below

```
user_id  total
1        15
2        17
```

I have come up with following code which only returns unique user ids.

```
SELECT distinct (meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key IN('tweet_user_id', 'email_user_id','chat_user_id','fb_user_id')
```

The above code returns me user ids then I run below query in loop to find points earned by user.

```
SELECT mm.meta_value from wp_postmeta  m , wp_postmeta  mm WHERE m.meta_value='1' AND mm.meta_key in ('tweet_point','email_point', 'fb_point',  'chat_point') GROUP BY mm.id
```

It returns me multiple rows for eg

```
meta_value
5
3
```

How can I sum these value in one row so that I don't need to loop again.

Comment: Where is  `user id` in your table example ?

Comment: @Ota-shavadeze Thanks for replying. There is no user_id column. The user_id is in table meta_key column for example tweet_user_id, email_user_id, chat_user_id,  fb_user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.

```
select user_id, count(post_id) as total from your_table group by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. There is no user_id column. The user_id is in table meta_key column for example tweet_user_id, email_user_id, chat_user_id,  fb_user_id

Comment: update your question please include all details so we can give you better answers

Comment: give a definite table structure so we can give you definite code

Comment: I have added some more details and example query that I have implemented currently.